# Parity of the class number of cyclotomic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields, ideal-class-group

I am interested if there are any heuristics on the parity of the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ where $\zeta_p$ is a primitive root of unity.

Is it true that it is odd infinitely many often? Is the density of primes for which it is odd known or conjectured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $h_p$ be the class number of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ and $h_p^+$ the class number of the maximal real subfield, then $h_p=h_p^+h_p^-$ for some integer $h_p^-$. Hasse proved that $h_p$ and $h_p^-$ have the same parity.

It is conjectured that the class number of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ is odd if $p$ is a Sophie-Germain prime, i.e. if $q=\frac{p-1}{2}$ is also prime. (This has been proven by [Estes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44237253) if one assumes that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $p$) and it is conjectured that there are infinitely many Sophie-Germain primes.